# How to call (show) another View Controller when clicked on the cell of Table View in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, action, tableview

I'm new in Swift. I want to learn that, how to call another View Controller when the user clicks on cell of Table View.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us what have you tried so far?

Comment: Follow this tutorial:http://www.codingexplorer.com/segue-uitableviewcell-taps-swift/

Comment: I hold on "control" button and drag the cell of table view to another view contoller. Then, I select "push" option under the "Selection Segue". But I get an error when I click on the cell.

Comment: @DharmeshKheni has provided you with a link to a tutorial. Follow the tutorial and your questions will be answered. Alternatively, follow an iTunesU course like `Developing iOS 8 Apps in Swift` (aka CS193P) from Stanford.

Answer (score 3):

write following code :

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showItemDetail", sender: tableView)}

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
if segue.identifier == "showItemDetail" {
    let indexPath:NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
    let detailVC:ItemDetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as ItemDetailViewController
    detailVC.item = items[indexPath.row] as Item
}
```

}

add a viewController from storyboard and add a segue from tableview cell to viewController with identifier "showItemDetail";
will navigate too detailViewController

Comment: Okay, but can you tell me, what does "items" mean? I get an error like this: "Use of unresolved identifier 'items' "

Answer (score 2):

*In First View Controller*

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!)
{
   if segue.identifier == "showItemDetail" 
   {
    let indexPath:NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
    let destination = segue.destinationViewController as DetailViewController
    destination.name = "llkin Elimov"
}
```

*In second Detail View Controller*

```
public DetailViewController
{
    var name = "name" as String //After you created the segue in      main.storyboard, in name , you will get your parsed string automatically

}
```

Hope my code is clear for you :)

Comment: Thanks for all, but I already solved this problem two month ago :)