# How to call view controller with parameters when button clicked in table view cell

Tags: ios, parameter-passing, swift2, viewcontroller

I was add the target in my button

```
cell.foo.tag = indexPath.row
cell.foo.addTarget(self, action: "bar:", forControlEvents:UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```

But I don't know how to call view controller with parameters

```
func bar(sender: UIButton!) {
   // ?
}
```

Comment: What do u want exactly?

Comment: like  [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28695969/how-to-call-show-another-view-controller-when-clicked-on-the-cell-of-table-vie)

Comment: u want to go to different view controller as per pertcular cel gets clickedl?

Comment: yeah2 i want to go to different view controller

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22759167/how-to-make-a-push-segue-when-a-uitableviewcell-is-selected follow this link

Answer (score 1):

You have to manually by using sender tag

```
func bar(sender: UIButton!) {

    if sender.tag == 0 {

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("viewcontroller1", sender: tableView)
    }
    else if sender.tag == 1 {

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("viewController2", sender: tableView)
    }
    //...... and so on
}
```

And implement following method

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

    if segue.identifier == "viewController1" {

        let indexPath:NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
        let detailVC = segue.destinationViewController as ViewController1
        detailVC.item = items[indexPath.row] as Item // Pass your data
    }
    else if segue.identifier == "viewController2" {


    }
    //...... and so on
}
```

Or if you want to navigate manually from button event then

```
func bar(sender: UIButton!) {

    if sender.tag == 0 {

        let indexPath:NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
        let detailVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("view1SegueIdentifier") as! ViewController1 // view1SegueIdentifier -> assign it from storyboard
        detailVC.item = items[indexPath.row] as Item // Pass your data
        self.navigationController!.pushViewController(detailVC, animated:true)
    }
    else if sender.tag == 1 {


    }
    //...... and so on
}
```